# How to look what other players inventory contains?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a site that can make servers in MC PC. I run one and I want my friends to come here so i can troll them. Do you guys know the command for looking in players inventory?

Comment: Do you run any plugins?

Answer (score 5):

To look a player inventory:

```
/data get entity @p Inventory
```

To look a chest inventory:

```
/data get block 0 0 0 Items
```

To set a player inventory in a chest **and clean his inventory** (command block):

```
execute at @p run data modify block 762 70 1565 Items set from entity @p Inventory 

clear @p
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are using a multiplayer server, the common (and useful) [Essentials](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentials) plugin comes with an in-build command to view a player's inventory. You can use the `/invsee <name>` command to achieve this.

You can also modify a users inventory using this command.

Answer (score 2):

In Minecraft Vanilla 1.12.2 you can't look up other player's inventories, you can only test if a certain item is in it. But in 1.13 (and already in the snapshots) you can use `/data get entity <player>` to get all data of a player. If you add `Inventory` to it, it only shows the inventory.